# I am using Vite with react and I am getting a proxy error

Tags: reactjs, proxy, vite

I am using Vite with react but when i use fetch/axios to make a request, I am getting an error.

My frontend runs on port 3000 and backend on port 5000.

My vite.config.js looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
      port: 3000,
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false,
          ws: true,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      }
    },
   
    
  }
})
```

When I try to make a call to the backend, it still makes a call to http://127.0.0.1:3000.

Here is the error message it shows:

POST http://localhost:3000/api/movies/440/addMovieComment 404 (Not Found)

I also tried to add proxy to the client's package.json file.

```
"proxy" : "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
```

However, it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You are `rewriting` the `request path` when it's been sent to your API server. Please remove the `rewrite` option and try again.

Comment: I removed it and tried again but it still gives same error.